# How to programmatically save files (.csv) from local machine running c# application to virtual machine

Tags: c#, connection, virtual-machine

Hey guys so I have this one c# application which outputs these .csv's and I want it to send it to a virtual machine which has a python application that will pick up these files and do some data analysis on it. Is there any way to create a connection between the c# application and the virtual machine so that I can save the .csvs in the virtual machine directory for pickup by the python script.

Comment: I think `python` tag isn't necessary here.

Comment: Thanks, i was perhaps thinking that there could be a python tool that allows user to pick up files from a known shared directory.

Comment: @giomadz why does there need to be a connection? Just save the files to the shared directory and then have your python script run on a schedule and check for new files?

Comment: @ivcubr would that be the best method? It doesn't necessarily need to create a connection, I just need a way for them to communicate.

Comment: IMO that is going to be the easiest solution. Another more complex option could be to trigger some event when you save a new csv file which removes the need to have python poll the shared folder

Comment: Please post the code you have now and what is not working. how are you saving the files now?

Comment: Files now are just being saved to a local directory then manually transferred to vm with python application that operates on them. Can't post any code unfortunately because its for work, ideally people in the field not on the network should be able to save files to that shared directory

Comment: @giomadz You just didn't mention you want to use Python here. If so, feel free to add this tag. If you want to code it only in C#, don't.

Comment: @giomadz instead of saving to a local directory just update that path to be the shared folder. Any reason this doesn't work?

Comment: @ivcubr shared folders only work if the vm and local machine is on the same network right? Employees in the field wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: @giomadz yes they would have to be on the same network. If the saving program is not they can you use a temp cloud storage and then have python on your other network download and remove them from there as it pulls them down to the VM?

Comment: @ivcubr yea thats the solution I'm coming to as well. Would dropbox be the best cloud storage to use for this? Do they have good API for python and c#?

Comment: would sharepoint be easier?

Comment: AFAIK it is fairly good. really depends on your application. Maybe google drive would be an option too. Just look for documentation on their APIs

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could create a Dropbox (or similar service) account, point your C# app to write the CSVs to this folder, and then access Dropbox from the VM for your Python app to pickup said CSVs.

You could also create a share on the VM, map it on the host (as long as you are on the same subnet, the VM has its own IP and is not bridged on the physical host's IP), have the C# app write the CSVs to this share, then point your Python app to parse the CSVs from the network share within the VM.

In Addition:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("sourcePath", "\\machinename\share folder path");
```

HTHs!

Comment: System.IO.File.Copy("sourcePath", "\\machinename\share folder path");

Does this only work on the same network?

Comment: Yes, this will only work on the same network. As I mentioned in my earlier post, if your VM has it's own IP, and it is on the same subnet (i.e. network) then you should be able to see the share from your host. Here's a link that details how to do this in VMWare Workstation [VMWare Shared Folder Info](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html)